# Trying to translate a linux shell script loop to Windows + GnuWin32

Tags: shell, loops, batch-file

**Edited to remove unnecessary usage of the "cat" command...**

I have a Linux shell script that reads data out of a CSV file and performs operations based on the last column of each line in the file.

The input file has this basic format:

```
asdf,foo
1234,foo
qwerty,bar
zxcv,baz
7890,bar
```

The original Linux script looks like this:

```
sed s/.*,//g $1 | sort -u | while read item
do
   # Do stuff with $item
done
```

I'm having a tough time translating the Linux script to run in a Windows shell environment with GnuWin32 versions of cat, sed, and sort.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('sed s/.*,//g %1 ^| sort -u') do (some stuff with %%A)
```

When I try to run this, I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command
cat: write error: Invalid argument
```

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something rudimentary about batch scripting.  I tried to cover some basics like [escape sequences](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), but I'm still drawing a blank.  Any hints?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you provide a sample set of CSV records (that produce the errors you've listed)?

Comment: @JubjubBandersnatch, just updated it.  Thanks!

Comment: you know that `cat $1 | ....` is considered bad form? Sed should work with a file (list) as the trailing arguments, i.e. `sed 's/x/y/g' f1 f2 ...`. Also you usually want to pass the inline script to sed as shown here, inside single-quotes, else put it in a file, and call it like `sed -f mySedScript.sed f1 f2 ...` . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter, great feedback!  I will update the Linux script accordingly.

Comment: When I quote the command given to sed, I don't get an error. This cmd eliminates the cat command, though it wasn't responsible for any errors as far as I could tell: `for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('sed "s/.*,//g" "%~1" ^| sort -u') do @echo %%A`

Also, make sure that you're using the GNU sort and not sort.exe that comes with Windows.

Comment: @JubjubBandersnatch, I think that did the trick.  Simply adding the double quotes was enough to stop the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cat "%~1" ^| sed "s/.*,//g" ^| sort -u') do (some stuff with %%A)
```

In Windows replace the single quotes from linux shell script `'` with double quotes `"`. If you need double quotes in GNUWin commands, it must be escaped by a backslash `\` - but only on the Windows shell prompt `cmd`, the scripts from `sed`, `awk` etc. are fully compatible.

Comment: Looks like `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('sed "s/.*,//g" %1 ^| sort -u') do (some stuff with %%A)` will work too...  Thanks!

Comment: You should better use `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('sed "s/.*,//g" "%~1" ^| sort -u') do (some stuff with %%A)`. And yes, `cat` is not neccessary. BTW the `Windows` command for `cat` is `type`.